# kubernetes consumes preserved network ip address

Tags: kubernetes

I am learning kubernetes in my home network. which is configured like this:

```
-192.168.1.1(router)
    -192.168.1.30(ubuntu machine 1, master node)
    -192.168.1.71(ubuntu machine 2, worker node)
```

My router ip 192.168.1.1 can not be modified. When I execute `sudo kubeadm init  --pod-network-cidr=192.168.1.0/24` in master node, master node iptable adds cni0 like below, and other nodes inside network(like ubuntu machine 2) becomes unavailable to connect

```
361: cni0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 32:61:29:d2:1d:16 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.1.1/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global cni0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::3061:29ff:fed2:1d16/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

what could be the problem? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another IP-range  (private) for your cluster, like 10.10.x.x.
Do not use the network on which your nodes a runing.

```
--pod-network-cidr=10.10.10.0/24
```

This will create a range of 255 ipaddresses each node can use for the pods, when they starts. so called clusterIps.

You need also a network fabric like flannel or calico.

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flannel-io/flannel/v0.20.2/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

Or you wont be able to connect to your cluster.